# Ionic-Deep Linking

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I am using **cordovaSocialSharingSource** plugin to share a link and **customUrlScheme** to create a custom url.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mycoolapp
```

mycooapp:// is not clickable.
How do I make it clickable?

Comment: We're going to need more details to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Many places you would be putting a link will not recognize custom URL schemes as valid, clickable URLs. The best workaround is to embed that custom URL address inside a normal `http://` link, and then do an automatic redirect. The new App Links (Android 6+) and Universal Links (iOS 9+) standards also help with this, because you're able to register a normal website URL to open your app instead of (or in addition to) using a custom URL scheme.

This is the approach we take at [Branch.io](https://branch.io). If you don't want to deal with building this out yourself, we have a Cordova SDK :)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic just rolled out their own support for deep linking so make sure you check that out in the [official docs](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/). The repo is [on Github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks).

Comment: I have gone through the repo but the problem is stil the same,
How do I make the following clickable in the mobile.
mycoolapp://

I have hyperlinked it with www.mycoolapp.com and it works fine, but that's not a permanent solution.

Comment: Hello @Abhay Kumar how did you deal with this issue i have also same problem if i make custom url scheme it is not clickable please reply to this how to proceed.